# React router hash history

Tags: reactjs

I was study about hashHistory vs browserHistory and stuck on the point 'Hash history not required any server side configuration'. I didn't understand about this point, Please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you setup react-router to use 'hash history'...

```
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
```

... it adds these strange looking # strings (hash strings) at the end of your URLs. The router uses the information contained in the string to render the correct components for the particular page that is requested.

If you don't want the hash strings appearing at the end of your URL, you can setup react-router to create real URLs that look like `example.com/some/path`. Internally react-router will make sure the correct components for that route are rendered.

There is only one problem.  Now if someone accesses `example.com/some/path` your server will try to find that page in your website directory instead of handing the request over to your react router. Your server doesn't know how to handle the URL.

You will have to configure the server to always deliver your app no matter what URL comes in. Then your app, in the browser, will manipulate the URL to return the correct page. That's why you will also need some configuration on the server, when you want to use

```
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
```

for better looking urls

[Here is some info](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md) on the difference between browser history (nice looking url's) and hash history (# sign in the url)

You don't write what server you are using. There are some server configuration examples (nginx, apache) [in the documentation.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory)

Comment: Are there any reason why would we use `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory`?